# When microphone is activated, bluetooth headset speakers produce noise

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth, microphone, headset

I'm using an August EP 650, connected via Bluetooth dongle to my desktop PC running Windows 7.

The headphones work as intended. But as soon as I activate the microphone in windows settings (these settings http://postimg.org/image/ppghiwx23/) it kills the sound coming from the headphone part of the headset. And by that I mean that they start producing this kind of noise http://picosong.com/4xuG/

It's always the same type of noise and it only happens when I play audio to my headset. But the noises come at seemingly random intervals. It definitely doesn't resemble my music.

Using the complete headset (mic and headphones) works fine on my Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini.

How do I fix this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: As for the edit, I would recommend that you visit [Why can people edit my posts? How does editing work?](http://superuser.com/help/editing) in the site's help center. In short, editing content here is allowed and is often done to curate content without changing its meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the little speaker button in your system tray, select "Recording Devices", select the microphone you're trying to use, and then click "Properties". Go to the "Listen" tab and uncheck "Listen to this device". Hope that will fix it.

Comment: Sadly, that box was already unchecked. I even installed the English language pack to make sure I was looking at the right tab and option. Got any other suggestions? :)